# $Y=F(X) \implies Y\sim U(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have a doubt on this theorem:

> The probability integral transform states that if ${\displaystyle X}$ is a continuous random variable with cumulative distribution function ${\displaystyle F_{X}}$, then the random variable ${\displaystyle Y=F_{X}(X)}$  has a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$.

The theorem is longer, but I don't understand this first part. If I have a continuous $F(X)$ and I set $Y=F(X)$, then this implies that $Y\sim U(0,1)$? Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since $X$ is a continuous random variable, for any $y$ with $0 \lt y \lt 1$  we have an $x$ with $F_X(x)=y$,

so $F_Y(y)=  P(Y\le y)= P(F_X(X)\le y)=P(X\le x)=F_X(x)=y$

meaning that $Y \sim U(0,1)$

Comment: This is better than the other answer, the only thing to be mentioned is that the result doesn't depend on which $x$ you picked, if $x$ happens to be non-unique.

Comment: @Ian: Indeed, and that becomes particularly relevant if $X$ is bounded and you then want to extend to $0 \le y \le 1$

Comment: Could you detail how you went from $P(F_X(X) \leq y)$ to $P(X \leq x)$? Or I guess from $P(F_X(X) \leq F_X(x))$ to $P(X \leq x)$ ?

Comment: @matthieu: In general any cdf $F_X(x)$ is a weakly increasing function of $x$ so  $P(F_X(X) \leq F_X(x)) $ $=P((F_X(X) \lt F_X(x))\cup(F_X(X) = F_X(x))) $ $=P(F_X(X) \lt F_X(x)) +P(F_X(X) $ $= F_X(x)) $ $=P(X<x)+P(X=x) = P(X\le x)$.  As an aside, note that in this case you have a continuous random variable so $P(X=x)=0$.

Comment: Okay, so how do you go from $P(F_X(X) \lt F_X(x))$ to $P(X \lt x)$ ? Can I do that for any increasing function $f$? Like $P(f(X) \lt f(x)) = P(X \lt x)$ ? Or is it specific to $F_X$ as the distribution function of $X$?

Comment: @matthieu $P(f(X) \lt f(x)) = P(X \lt x)$ is true for any strictly increasing function $f$, but not for some weakly increasing functions $f$ as there may be a set of values just below $x$ where $f(y)=f(x)$ and this set may have positive probability $P(\{y:f(y)=f(x)\})$.  But in the case of $F_X$ when it is continuous you have $P(\{y:F_X(y)=F_X(x)\}) =0$